# Plot Eigenvalues with respect to a parameter

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

I have a parametrical matrix (18x18) which I want to plot its eigenvalues with respect to a parameter.
For simplicity, lets assume that it is instead a 3x3 matrix which is not fully numerical but depends on a parameter Y. So that all eigenvalues depend on Y as well.
I need to plot all eigenvalues with respect to Y in a single plot (Y in the x-axis). Any suggestions?

In addition, would you please explain if I use Eigenvectors[A] to get eigenvectors (depending on Y), are the result normalized or I need to normalize them myself?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Symbolic eigenvectors will not be normalized.

Comment: What do you want to plot when some of the eigenvalues are complex? Or is your matrix structured so that they are all real-valued?

Comment: @bills at the end they are all real-valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = {{x, 1 + x}, {1 - x, x}};
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[a]
Plot[eigenvalues, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> `{x - Sqrt[1 - x^2], x + Sqrt[1 - x^2]}`

[image]